# body append doesn't work on different pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two pages. I want to use JS to add a same footer on both pages.

one is index.html
second is add_dish.html

Here is my module.js

```
DCGAPP.DIV.FOOTER.createFooter = function(){
    var divBegin = '<div data-role="footer" data-id="tab" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed"><div data-role="navbar"><ul>'
    var menuFirst = '<li><a href="index.html">OPEN</a></li>'
    var menuSecond = '<li><a href="add_dish.html">ADD</a></li>'
    var divEnd = '</ul></div></div>'

    $('body').append(divBegin+menuFirst+menuSecond+divEnd);
}
```

I call DCGAPP.DIV.FOOTER.createFooter(); on main.js

**when I firstly load index.html by default , the footer was successfully created.
However, when I click "ADD" (direct me to add_dish.html), the footer was not created**
PS:even if I move both my script into head, it gave me the same result
both my html is the same :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/serverclient.min.css">
    <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        test
    </div>
    <!-- /content -->

    <!-- /footer -->
<script src="js/module.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Any errors in console? Can't you use PHP to include files?

Comment: Nope. did not have any error on console. I am developing only frontend logic.

Answer (score -1):

on your module.js fix your code (add #).

```
$('#body').append(divBegin+menuFirst+menuSecond+divEnd);
```

also on your add_dish.html make sure your jquery are included.

Comment: whats the error on your bowser console (press f12 on firefox or chrome)?

Comment: it gave me a warning " Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. "

Comment: There is no difference to select directly `<body>` element or select it by ID

Comment: I common out jquery mobile element. At least footer was added in both page (just without css style) . So I guess this is a jq mobile problem? There must be a way to reuse a div cross different pages.